# How to malloc array of structs without knowing size

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a struct of words:

```
typedef struct {
   char *word;
   unsigned long occurrences;
} Word;
```

and I want to malloc an array of these but I don't know how large the size will be. Is there a way to malloc an array of structs without knowing the size of the array beforehand?

Thanks.

Comment: heh? if you don't know the size, what's the point of allocating memory?

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can allocate memory with `malloc()`, and then change  size with `realloc()`

```
typedef struct {
 char *word;
 unsigned long occurrences;
} Word;

int main()
{
  Word *arr = malloc(sizeof(Word) * n);
  // do smth
  // need more
  arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(Word) * more);

  return 0;
}
```